# Simplifying an Expression further

Tags: real-numbers

I have trouble doing this and I'm not sure why are they the same and what are the steps I need to do to reach the simplified answer.

For example ...

$\frac{-8}{\sqrt{128}}$

This is the same as

$\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} $

> I'm not sure how to reach the simplified expression from the earlier expression .. Can anyone help me ? Thanks !

Comment: the Mathjax code for the square root function is sqrt{yourvaluehere}

Answer (score 5):

$\frac{-8}{\sqrt {128}} = $$\frac{-8}{\sqrt 2 \sqrt {64}} = \frac{(-1)(8)}{\sqrt2(8)} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt2}$

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps: $$\frac {-8}{\sqrt{128}}=$$Simplify the bottom fraction $$ \frac {-8}{8\sqrt{2}}$$ cancel out the 8's $$ \frac {-1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 4):

$\frac{-8}{\sqrt{128}}=-(\frac{8}{\sqrt{128}})=-(\sqrt{\frac{8^2}{(\sqrt{128})^2}})=-(\sqrt{\frac{64}{128}})=-(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}})=-(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$

In general, put the minus symbol outside, then try to simplify the content of the square root of the perfect square of numerator and denominator (the will be $a^2$ and $b$):

> $$\frac{-a}{\sqrt{b}}=-(\frac{a}{\sqrt{b}})=-(\sqrt{(\frac{a}{\sqrt{b}})^2})=-(\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{(\sqrt{b})^2}})=-(\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b}})$$